# Questions about better solution to keep comments and votes in one document

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for a better way to handle it. My documents I designed to store all comments and votes (like a confirmation thats stores picture and text information as well) using arrays inside a document. The issue I'm concerning is about the size limit of a document (16 Mb so far), If a document keeps a lot of comments and specially votes in internal arrays, very probably it will be broken reaching the size limit, on the other hand, keep this strategy I can ensure faster queries as well.

What do I have to do? Do like a relational DB and keep these kind of information and different collections and docs? It will decrease search speed, otherwise I'll keep it safe and unbroken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you plan on using the data.  If you get a huge number of comments on a single blog post would you really want to query for the post and get *all* the comments back?

No real life webpage that shows you a blog post actually does that.  They show you the first few comments and then fetch more either as you scroll through those or when you click "show more".  That's probably the best (hybrid) model.  Store what you need when you first display a blog post *in* the blog post document but keep everything else that you can query for later in a separate collection where every comment references the post that it belongs to.  Then you can get the additional comments with a single indexed read (probably index it on post_id and date posted?).  You can also use the "bucketing" technique and store comments grouped by post and chunk of time so that you can fetch entire "next page of comments" document.

If you architect this correctly rather than *reducing* your search speed it will likely *increase* your search and reading speed for base documents and save you a lot of network bandwidth too.

Comment: I like this aproach. I was thinking to answer the same. All depends on how many comments will the application manage and how you want to manage them. Nice answer.

Comment: I'll looking for this approach you say. Try bucketing technique. Yes, I think about date and my other doc ID for indexes. This is not will be a blog and my concerning is more about votes than comments. Maybe votes can reach more than 30k per "post". Thanks

Comment: then it depends on whether you plan to keep just the vote counter in the document itself or the voters list as well.  It makes sense to embed the voters for multiple reasons but on a system where you might have this many of them you have to consider the trade-offs of storing them separately.